# Is the Confluent Platform 7.1 based on Kafka free? open source? for production use

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I have usecase to start using Kafka and was looking for opensource free (production) kafka.

When check Confluent 7.1 platform looks suitable as it has zookeeper / kafka / schema registry / kafka UI bundled together.

Before deciding to go ahead with it just want to check if the Confluent Platform 7.1 is free and open source? Am I required to purchase licensing or paid support?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Confluent Community License](https://www.confluent.io/confluent-community-license-faq/) covers several components of Confluent Platform, including KSQLDB, the Schema Registry, REST Proxy, and various Kafka Connect plugins. Confluent Control Center (what you call Kafka UI) is only available on a trial basis, outside of which requires Enterprise license payment.

Majority of Confluent Platform individual components are "source-available", and free with limitations. Many of the plugin features like RBAC, Tiered Storage, Cluster Linking, and server-side Kafka record Schema Validation require payment. This is an Enterprise license and also includes Control Center, on-call Support, and several other connectors.

---

Apache Kafka, it's clients, and Zookeeper are Apache 2.0 licensed.

If you want a completely Apache 2.0 stack, you can replace Confluent Schema Registry with Apicurio and replace Control Center with various Kafka GUI projects that exist on Github, such as AKHQ or CMAK